# Retrieve first email from string in SQL row

Tags: sql, string

Good morning,
I have an email column in a table that contains **in some rows** more than one email, separated by a semicolon.
Actually i am trying to retrieve the email with this query

```
-- cdu_mail is the column

select
    ltrim(rtrim(cdu_mail)),
    substring(ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail)), 0, charindex(';',ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail)))) 
FROM Clientes
```

If i have more than one mail in the row the query retrieves correctly the first email, but if there is only one email in the row the result is blank.

[image]

What do i need to change to get all the mails correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5493616/679449). Just uses comma instead of semicolon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also tack on a semi-colon at the end of the column to guarantee a semi-colon will always exist, and avoid using case expressions:

```
select     ltrim(rtrim(cdu_mail)),     
    substring(ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail)), 0, charindex(';',ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail + ';')))) 
FROM #Clientes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put this into a case statement:

```
select (case when cdu_email like '%;'
             then ltrim(rtrim(cdu_mail)), substring(ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail)), 0,
                                                    charindex(';',ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail))))
             else cdu_email
        end) as firstEmail
from Clientes
```

The problem is that one email does not end in a ';', so the charindex() returns 0.

I realize, you can also solve this by appending a semicolon for that particular search as well:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(cdu_mail)), substring(ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail)), 0,
                                         charindex(';',ltrim(RTRIM(cdu_mail+';'))))
from Clientes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    select  case when charindex(';', cdu_mail) = 0 then cdu_mail else
                    substring(cdu_mail,1, charindex(';', cdu_mail) - 1) end
    from    clientes
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of SQL syntax you are using but in MySQL you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    IF( LOCATE(  ";", TRIM( cdu_mail ) ) >1, LEFT( TRIM( cdu_mail ), 
    LOCATE(  ";", TRIM( cdu_mail ) ) -1 ), 
    TRIM( cdu_mail ) ) AS email
FROM Clientes
```

Effectively if there is a ";", pick the first email out, otherwise just get the value of the field (since there is only one email).

You might also want to introduce checking for NULL values with a WHERE clause.

HTH